# GoogleOAuth with passport, graphql-yoga and prisma

Tags: passport.js, graphql, prisma

Currently, I’m building login feature via Google and I have some problems that make a little bit confusing for me.

Can we use both Restful API and Graphql API in one project? Except for the Google Authentication, we need to some route to handle that. For CRUD operations, we use Graphql.

Something like this:

```
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga');
const { Prisma } = require('prisma-binding');
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {

  // mongoose.
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user);
  });

});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(
  {
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile);

    // After receive profile info from google, call mutation and save
    // profile into database.
  }
));

const db = new Prisma({
  typeDefs: 'src/generated/prisma.graphql',
  endpoint: process.env.PRISMA_ENDPOINT,
  debug: true,
  secret: process.env.PRISMA_SECRET,
});

const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  resolverValidationOptions: {
    requireResolversForResolveType: false
  },
  context: req => ({ ...req, db })
});

server.express.get('/auth/connect', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['profile', 'email']
}));

server.express.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google'));

server.start(() => console.log(`Server is running on ${process.env.PRISMA_ENDPOINT}`));
```

In callback function of `GoogleStrategy`, how can I call Mutation and save all profile info from Google to database?

```
(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile);

    // After receiving profile info from google, call mutation and save
    // profile into the database.
  }
```

And in `deserializeUser` and `serializeUser` function. Before, when I’m working with Nodejs and MongoDB I have done this:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
   done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {

  // mongoose.
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user);
  });

});
```

And with Prisma and Graphql, how to do this problem with mutation?

Answer (score 0):

In your server, you create the `prisma-binding` instance, that you then passes to the context of `graphql-yoga`. This allows you to make prisma operations in your resolvers like so:

```
context.db.query.user({where: {id: 'ABCD'}})
```

But that doesn't mean you can't use the `prisma-binding` instance somewhere else!

In your passport callbacks, you can access your `prisma-binding` instance and call queries and mutations too:

```
db.mutation.createUser({data: {name: 'John Doe'}})
```